# Concern about CS Theory site fracturing the [algorithm] tag on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, migration

The proliferation of underpopulated SE sites is an item of discussion, but here am concerned about one particular effect: the fracturing of the [algorithm] tag on SO.

For a long time algorithmic, or partially algorithmic, questions have been asked on SO and tagged with the [algorithm] tag. There are tens of thousands of such questions on SO. Now with the CS Theory site, what is happening is that random [algorithm] questions are being migrated to the CS Theory, or just closed as "off topic". There is no rhyme or reason other than random chance. In theory I suppose 90% of the [algorithm] tagged posts could be moved to CS Theory, but the problem is that SO has nearly 2 million users and practically nobody uses CS Theory. Who wants to post a question to a forum with 11,000 (low time) users when you could post to SO with almost 2,000,000 users? Nobody. Getting migrated to CS is like getting your post deleted.

Also, as an algorithm "answerer" I do not want to visit two different forums. I do not want to be switching back and forth. Also I DEFINITELY do not want my badge/rep efforts to be split between two forums. I want my rep to be on ONE site, SO, because that is where I am asking my questions, which are often not algorithm related.

I used to paticipate in a machining forum and posted to General a set of really interesting photos that would be of general interest to machinists and the moderator force moved my post to the "fabrication" sub forum that had literally <1% of the population of the general forum just because some of the photos were tangentially fabrication related. It was more or less equivalent to deleting my post, that I spent a LOT of time on. I stopped using that forum.

I am wondering if anybody agrees with me that this is a serious problem that is causing fragmentation in posts in the [algorithm] tag and what we can do about it?

------------------------------ EXAMPLE

To provide a concrete example, here is some guy's post: [TSP question post on SO that got migrated](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/evolutionary-algorithm-for-the-physical-travelling-salesman-problem). This one actually got migrated to "Computer Science", but just as well similar posts are getting migrated to CS Theory. Why this one got migrated, but 10 others very similar didn't, who knows? In my view this post was a completely legitimate [algorithm] post that could have, and should have been answered on SO.

Answer (score 5):

From their [about](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/about) page:

> Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
>   **researchers** in theoretical computer science and related fields.

There's a lot less overlap between Stack Overflow and CS Theory than some people seem to realize, even when there are tags that overlap.  Very few of the [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) questions on Stack Overflow would be suitable for CS Theory.  They are  just not research-level problems, so should not be migrated.

Comment: Yes, if it is strictly theory maybe, but what is happening is that some guy makes a question like "I have problem X that seems to a Travelling Salesman problem. What is the best algorithm for this?" and then, boom, closed or migrated.

Comment: @TylerDurden I just looked through the most recent 250 algorithm questions posted on Stack Overflow and I see that that's only happened [once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16960454/1288), and [that question did get answered on CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12485/1238).  I don't see this as a trend or a serious problem.  If there are questions closed that shouldn't be, I think there are few enough of them that they can be handled individually by flagging for moderators.

Comment: You should be able to flag those to be unmigrated, no?

Comment: @KateGregory No, there's no such thing as unmigration. It's possible for the destination to reject the migration, but only if it's off-topic there after all. It's possible to disassociate the migration and reopen on the source site, but that would only be done if it turned out the question was on-topic on the source site **and** there was a serious reason to leave it there — normally we wouldn't want to have two copies of the question.

Answer (score 4):

First, get your facts right. There are two different sites, [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) and [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Theoretical Computer Science is for research-level questions about theoretical computer science. It's extremely rare for a question posted on Stack Overflow to be suitable for TCS.SE, and such migrations very rarely happen. It's rather more common for questions posted on SO to be suitable on SE — I would estimate at a handful on a busy day, making somewhat less than 0.1%.

There is some overlap between SO and CS.SE when it comes to algorithms questions. A question that is purely about the design or the analysis of an algorithm (such as [Evolutionary algorithm for the Physical Travelling Salesman Problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/evolutionary-algorithm-for-the-physical-travelling-salesman-problem)), is off-topic on SO. Conversely, a question that is specifically about a particular implementation effort for a given algorithm would be off-topic on CS.SE but is squarely on-topic on SO. In the middle, there is a fairly large class of questions that are about solving a specific algorithmic problem with implementation in mind, which could be asked on either site. These questions won't be migrated since they aren't off-topic whichever site they were asked on.

In the old days (i.e. a couple of years ago), SO would be inclusive of many questions that weren't about programming but about vaguely related topics, such as system administration, general computer usage, computer science, mathematics, sociology of the programming profession, intellectual property law, etc. The problem with this is that the further you stray from the group's core expertise, the more hit-and-miss the quality becomes. Stack Exchange operates on a fundamentally different basis from, say, Quora: here, the goal is for questions to reach a target audience of specialists, answered and curated by subject experts.

The spread of topics on SO was a serious problem; fortunately, it is slowly being solved. Communities now exist for those vaguely-related topics ([Super User](https://superuser.com/) and several more specialized sites for general computer usage, [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) for professional system administration, [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), …).

Given a choice of 2,000,000 people, 1,999,950 of whom who won't see the question and wouldn't understand it anyway, or 11,000 people who might actually know the answer, the best choice is obvious.

> There is no rhyme or reason other than random chance.

It's true that a lot of off-topic questions are left languishing on SO. Please help by monitoring your favorite tags and flagging the off-topic questions for migration to a more suitable site.

> Getting migrated to CS is like getting your post deleted.

Yes, Belgium you too. Seriously, since you're interested in algorithms, how about participating on a site where people discuss the topic? We don't bite on CS.SE, you know. We're even polite.

Stack Exchange makes it very easy to participate on multiple sites. You can make a [tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters) to watch the [algorithms] questions on SO, CS and CSTheory.

> Also I DEFINITELY do not want my badge/rep efforts to be split between two forums. I want my rep to be on ONE site, SO, because that is where I am asking my questions, which are often not algorithm related.

Well, if you're only here for the badges and reputation, consider that by participating on two sites, you can get twice the badge and twice the reputation (the rep cap is per site). As for asking questions, you don't need any reputation for that. I recommend asking on a site where the audience is most likely to know the answer.